# Killing tasks spawned by a job

Tags: dask

I am considering if replacing celery with dask. Currently we have a cluster where different jobs are submitted, each one generating multiple tasks that run in parallel. Celery has a killer feature, the "revoke" command: I can kill all the tasks of a given job without interfering with the other jobs that are running at the same time. How can I do that with dask? I only find references saying that this is not possible, but for us it would be a disaster. So don't want to be force the shut down the entire cluster when a calculation goes rogue, thus killing the jobs of the other users.

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel tasks using the `Client.cancel` command.

If they haven't started yet then they won't start, however if they're already running in a thread somewhere then there isn't much that Python can do to stop them other than to tear down the process.

Comment: I am not talking about threads, I am talking about processes. For instance dask could send a signal (a SIGINT or a custom signal) to the tasks that should be killed (but not to the others)) and I could trap that signal inside the code that is running inside the worker and exit early. Without a revoke functionality selling dask at work would be very hard. We are doing numeric simulations, all the time one realizes that the calculation he has sent is to slow, or too big, or risk to send the cluster out of memory and decide to kill it before its natural conclusion. This is essential for us.

Comment: Dask tasks aren't run in standalone processes.  If you want to hard-kill a worker you generally rely on whatever mechanism you used to start those workers (Kubernetes, yarn, SGE, etc..)

Comment: If being able to explicitly kill any task that is running immediately is a requirement for you then it looks like Dask is not a good solution for your problem.